# How to login user after LWC custom community registration

Tags: apex, javascript, community, lightning-web-components, login

I have a custom portal/community registration page created using LWC, which uses:

```
Site.createExternalUser(...);
```

To create the user.

Once the user is created, I want to automatically log them into the portal and redirect them to an internal page.

I've tried using:

```
Site.login(username, password, null);
```

And returning `true` back to the LWC and doing a client-side redirect to the page, but it did not work.

**Questions**

1. What is wrong with the above approach?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: LWC actually lacks this feature. We built a similar code with passwordless login first with LWC and then with Aura but there as well we had issues that a user was not able to post chatter comments. So we ended up using VF page inside Aura for form submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working like this:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String createAccount(...) {

   // create account and user etc...

   ApexPages.PageReference pageRef = Site.login(...);

   return pageRef.getUrl();
}
```

Then on the client-side:

```
createAccount(...)
    .then(data => {
        if (data) {
            window.location.href = data;
        } 
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```